# Calculation Issue (not a math problem, but I just need help with calculation)

Tags: calculator

[image]

For a) I just plugged in e to the equation and got the answer. I am stuck on the rest.

So for b) I plugged in the CO2 they gave us into the e equation and then calculated e and plugged it into the Ts equation, but I keep getting an error on my calculator because I keep getting a negative number in the (2/2-e)^1/4 part and that shows an error in my calculator (my e is really huge).

I don't know what to do!

Comment: Your $\epsilon$ should not be huge...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your epsilon should be less than $1$.  If you multiply $410 \times 0.0001$ what do you get?

Comment: shouldn't i do 0.0001^-1 first?

Comment: Ah ha!  That's where things are going awry.  .0001 is not raised to the negative one.  The units are .

Comment: @PaddlingGhost oh so i just ignore the -1? and multiply 410 by 0.0001?

Comment: Thank you! so much! what units should I put for it then for the answer? I got 288.246

Comment: The $-1$ is an exponent on ppm, it is the units of the constant.  When you multiply ppm by ppm$^{-1}$ you get a unitless number.  When you take the fourth root it is still unitless.  The $T_e$ comes with the unit K for Kelvin, and that is the unit of the whole right side.  Another example would be if I count the dashes in the line in a road and find $470$ of them in a kilometer.  I could express the density of dashes as $470\ km^{-1}$.  If you then travel $13\ km$ you could say you passed $13 km \times 470\ km^{-1}=6110$ dashes.  The number of dashes has no units.